# postfix Temporary lookup failure NOQUEUE: reject

Tags: email, postfix

I get an error and don't know how to fix it. Sending is working alright.
This is my /var/log/mail.log:

```
Oct 26 17:15:23 pikachu postfix/smtpd[16360]: connect from mail-ee0-f51.google.com[74.125.83.51]
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/trivial-rewrite[16363]: warning: mysql query failed: Table 'mailserver.virtual_aliases' doesn't exist
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/trivial-rewrite[16363]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: table lookup problem
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/trivial-rewrite[16363]: warning: virtual_alias_domains lookup failure
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/trivial-rewrite[16363]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: table lookup problem
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/trivial-rewrite[16363]: warning: virtual_alias_domains lookup failure
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/smtpd[16360]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ee0-f51.google.com[74.125.83.51]: 451 4.3.0 <carlos@treadity.com>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<cvr.xx.cvr@gmail.com> to=<carlos@treadity.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ee0-f51.google.com>
Oct 26 17:15:24 pikachu postfix/smtpd[16360]: disconnect from mail-ee0-f51.google.com[74.125.83.51]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling with the sql database I found the solution. It turns out that forgot to create the alias table. Didn't knew i had to do that.